# CATiledLayer isnt working on my iOS5 project

Tags: linker, ios5, storyboard, catiledlayer

I have created new single view application (developing with iOS 5 sdk and Xcode 4.2), the app is now consisted of app delegate, view controller, scrollView (with CATiledLayer). Storyboard contains `ViewController` that contains `UIScrollView` which class is `ScrollView` (class that I have created). My goal is to display large PDF files, with zooming and etc. I based my project on zooming pdf sample from apple. When I try to run my app on iPad it crashes during linking showing me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATiledLayer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in TiledPDFPage.o
```

So does anyone know, how to avoid this error? Is it possible that the problem is in that I didnt create the scrollView in code but in storyboard??

Answer (score 9):

Did you remember to link the QuartzCore framework?

You probably have an import like this somewhere (Probably in your `TiledPDFPage.m`):

```
#import <QuartzCore/CATiledLayer.h>
```

If so you have to link in the QuartzCore framework too.

1. Click on the project name in the project Navigator (⇧⌘J to open the Navigator).
2. Click on the project Target.
3. Click on the Build Phases tab.
4. Open the Link Binary With Libraries list.
5. Check to see if `QuartzCore.framework` is already in the list.  If not, continue.
6. Click the +.
7. Type in QuartzCore.
8. Select `QuartzCore.framework` (you may have to expand the IOS 5 folder).
9. Click Add.
10. Build.